# Generic typed subcollection of a collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, types, filtering

I want to write a helper method that would return a genericly typed subcollection of an object collection, but I need some help with it!

Here is how I want to do it:

```
    public static <T> Collection<T> getTypeFilteredSubCollection(Collection<Object> objects) {
    Collection<T> typeFilteredCollection = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Object object : objects) {
        if(object instanceof T) {
            typeFilteredCollection.add((T)object);
        }
    }
    return typeFilteredCollection;
}
```

The obvious problem is that generic types will disappear runtime, but you get the idea what I am trying to do.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass the class of `T` along with it and use [`Class::isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getTypeFilteredSubCollection(Collection<Object> objects, Class<T> clazz) {
    Collection<T> typeFilteredCollection = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Object object : objects) {
        if(clazz.isInstance(object)) {
            typeFilteredCollection.add((T)object);
        }
    }
    return typeFilteredCollection;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `clazz.isInstance(object)`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman That would exclude subtypes, I assumed they would be wanted too.

Comment: Yes subclasses are neccessary. The generic type (and Class) I wanna pass this method would be an interface (most of the cases).

Comment: @JornVernee No, it doesn't exclude subtypes.  `clazz.isInstance` does what you want.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yeah I was just looking into that some more, seems I remembered wrongly. Using ```isIntance``` is a little nicer in that case :)

Comment: Also you might as well use `clazz.cast(object)` instead of `(T) object`, just to avoid the unchecked cast warning.